# Does GPars actors model uses user thread or native OS threads

Tags: concurrency, actor, gpars

I know when there is no message to process an actor does not consume thread and attaches itself to a thread only when message arrives. However my question is when an actors is attached to a thread what kind of thread it is - user thread or native OS thread?

I want to basically understand what will happen if there is some blocking code in actor, say some i/o call or waiting for response of web service?  Will the thread remain blocked or thread will be released and available to some other actor? As far as I think if it is native thread then it will be blocked. However if it is user thread then native thread might not be blocked

Answer (score 0):

IO operations within the actor body will block the current thread.